# How can I get ack to return results?

Tags: linux, search, ack, searching-xml

I know there's some text inside a file under $SOURCE/frameworks/base/res/res/values/strings.xml that says "hotspot," but if I am in the source directory and execute `ack hotspot`, I get "no file or directory."

This is my first time trying to navigate source code of a huge repo, so please be kind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally discovered why ack wasn't working. Via apt-get, `ack` is a Kanji code converter. ack is therefore called `ack-grep` in Ubuntu-based distributions.

Comment: You may be pleased to learn that the patch that renamed `ack` to `ack-grep` on Debian (and Ubuntu) has been removed. So you can simply invoke `ack` in Debian Sid (and probably in the next Ubuntu 14.10).

Comment: Glad to hear it. Right now, I'm simply using an alias.